# Bash scripting and large files (bug): input with the read builtin from a redirection gives unexpected result

Tags: bash

I have a strange issue with large files and `bash`.  This is the context:

- I have a large file: 75G and 400,000,000+ lines (it is a log file, my bad, I let it grow).
- The first 10 chars of each line is a time stamps in the format YYYY-MM-DD.
- I want to split that file: one file per day.

I tried with the following script that did not work.  **My question is about this script not working, not alternative solutions**.

```
while read line; do
  new_file=${line:0:10}_file.log
  echo "$line" >> $new_file
done < file.log
```

After debugging, I found the problem in the `new_file` variable.  This script:

```
while read line; do
  new_file=${line:0:10}_file.log
  echo $new_file
done < file.log | uniq -c
```

gives the result bellow (I put the `x`es to keep the data confidential, other chars are the real ones).  Notice the `dh` and the shorter strings:

```
...
  27402 2011-xx-x4
  27262 2011-xx-x5
  22514 2011-xx-x6
  17908 2011-xx-x7
...
3227382 2011-xx-x9
4474604 2011-xx-x0
1557680 2011-xx-x1
      1 2011-xx-x2
      3 2011-xx-x1
...
     12 2011-xx-x1
      1 2011-xx-dh
      1 2011-xx-x1
      1 208--
      1 2011-xx-x1
      1 2011-xx-dh
      1 2011-xx-x1    
...
```

**It is not a problem in the format of my file**.  The script `cut -c 1-10 file.log | uniq -c` gives only valid time stamps.  Interestingly, a part of the the above output becomes with `cut ... | uniq -c`:

```
3227382 2011-xx-x9
4474604 2011-xx-x0
5722027 2011-xx-x1
```

We can see that after the uniq count `4474604`, my initial script failed.

Did I hit a limit in bash that I do not know, did I find a bug in bash (it seams unlikely), or have I done something wrong ?

**Update**:

The problem happens after reading 2G of the file.  It seams `read` and redirection do not like larger files than 2G.  But still searching for a more precise explanation.

**Update2**:

It definitively looks like a bug.  It can be reproduced with:

```
yes "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrs" | head -n 100000000 > file
while read line; do file=${line:0:10}; echo $file; done < file | uniq -c
```

but this works fine as a workaround (it seams that I found a useful use of `cat`):

```
cat file | while read line; do file=${line:0:10}; echo $file; done | uniq -c
```

A bug has been filed to GNU and Debian.  Affected versions are `bash` 4.1.5 on Debian Squeeze 6.0.2 and 6.0.4.

```
echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}
4 1 5 1 release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

**Update3:**

Thanks to Andreas Schwab who reacted quickly to my bug report, this is the patch that is the solution to this misbehavior.  The impacted file is [`lib/sh/zread.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/sh/zread.c?id=17345e5ad288f7543b77b23a25aa380eacc279f2) as Gilles pointed out sooner:

```
diff --git a/lib/sh/zread.c b/lib/sh/zread.c index 0fd1199..3731a41 100644
--- a/lib/sh/zread.c
+++ b/lib/sh/zread.c @@ -161,7 +161,7 @@ zsyncfd (fd)
      int fd; {   off_t off;
-  int r;
+  off_t r;

  off = lused - lind;   r = 0;
```

The `r` variable is used to hold the return value of `lseek`.  As `lseek` returns the offset from the beginning of the file, when it is over 2GB, the `int` value is negative, which causes the test `if (r >= 0)` to fail where it should have succeed.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with smaller sets of input data?  Is it always the same input lines that result in these problems?

Comment: @larks: good question.  The problem always begins at line # 13.520.918 (twice actually for the tests I did).  The size of the file before this line is 2.147.487.726.  It seams that there is a 32 bits limit here, but not exactly as we are a little over 2^31 (2.147.483.648), but right at a 4K buffer limit (2^31 + 4K = 2.147.487.744).  The previous and next lines are normal 100 to 200 character lines.

Comment: Tested on a 2nd file (about same size): the problem begins at line # 13.522.712, and the file is 2.147.498.679 bytes large before that line.  It seams to point in the direction of a limit of the `read` statement in bash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've found a bug in bash, of sorts. It's a known bug with a known fix.

Programs represent an offset in a file as a variable in some integer type with a finite size. In the old days, everyone used `int` for just about everything, and the `int` type was limited to 32 bits, including the sign bit, so it could store values from -2147483648 to 2147483647. Nowadays there are different [type names for different things](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), including `off_t` for an offset in a file.

By default, `off_t` is a 32-bit type on a 32-bit platform (allowing up to 2GB), and a 64-bit type on a 64-bit platform (allowing up to 8EB). However, it's common to compile programs with the LARGEFILE option, which switches the type `off_t` to being 64 bits wide and makes the program call suitable implementations of functions such as [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/).

It appears that your're running bash on a 32-bit platform and your bash binary is not compiled with large file support. Now, when you read a line from a regular file, bash uses an internal buffer to read characters in batches for performance (for more details, see the source in [`builtins/read.def`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/read.def?id=b4d40164691e23c7c546daa57c411907a2c2e8cf)). When the line is complete, bash calls `lseek` to rewind the file offset back to the position of the end of the line, in case some other program cared about the position in that file. The call to `lseek` happens in the `zsyncfc` function in [`lib/sh/zread.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/lib/sh/zread.c?id=17345e5ad288f7543b77b23a25aa380eacc279f2).

I haven't read the source in much detail, but I surmise that something is not happening smoothly at the point of transition when the absolute offset is negative. So bash ends up reading at the wrong offsets when it refills its buffer, after it's passed the 2GB mark.

If my conclusion is wrong and your bash is in fact running on a 64-bit platform or compiled with largefile support, that is definitely a bug. Please report it to your distribution or [upstream](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html#Bugs).

A shell is not the right tool to process such large files anyway. It's going to be slow. Use sed if possible, otherwise awk.

Comment: Merci Gilles.  Great answer: complete, with enough information to understand the issue even to people without strong CS background (32 bits...).  (larsks also help in questioning on the line number, and it should be acknowledged.)  After that, I also though of a 32 bit problem and download the source, but was not yet to this level of analysis.  Merci encore, et bonne journée.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about wrong, but it's certainly convoluted.  If your input lines look like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DD some text ...
```

Then there's really no reason for this:

```
new_file=${line:0:4}-${line:5:2}-${line:8:2}_file.log
```

You're doing a lot of substring work to end up with something that looks...exactly the way it already looks in the file.  How about this?

```
while read line; do
  new_file="${line:0:10}_file.log"
  echo "$line" >> $new_file
done
```

That just grabs the first 10 characters from the line.  You could also dispense with `bash` entirely and just use `awk`:

```
awk '{print > ($1 "_file.log")}' < file.log
```

This grabs the date in `$1` (the first whitespace-delimited column in each line) and uses it to generate the filename.

Note that it is possible that there are some bogus log lines in your files.  That is, the problem may be with the input, not your script.  You could extend the `awk` script to flag bogus lines like this:

```
awk '
$1 ~ /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/ {
    print > ($1 "_file.log")
    next
}

{
    print "INVALID:", $0
}
'
```

This writes lines match `YYYY-MM-DD` to your log files, and flags lines that don't start with a timestamp on stdout.

Comment: No bogus lines in my file: `cut -c 1-10 file.log | uniq -c` gives me the expected result.  I am using `${line:0:4}-${line:5:2}-${line:8:2}` because I will put the file in a directory `${line:0:4}/${line:5:2}/${line:8:2}`, and I simplified the problem (I will update the problem statement).  I know `awk` can help me here, but I ran in other problems  using it.  What I want is understand the problem with `bash`, not find alternate solutions.

Comment: As you said...if you "simplify" the problem in the question, you're probably not going to get the answers you want.  I still think that solving this with bash is not really the right way to process this sort of data, but there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: The simplified problem gives the unexpected result that I presented in the question, so I do not think that it is an oversimplification.  Moreover, the simplified problem gives a similar result as the `cut` statement that works.  As I want to compare apples with apples, not with oranges, I need to make things as similar as possible.

Comment: I left you a question that might help figure out where things are going awry...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want to do is:

```
awk '
{  filename = substr($0, 0, 10) "_file.log";  # input format same as output format
   if (filename != lastfile) {
       close(lastfile);
       print 'finished writing to', lastfile;
   }
   print >> filename;
   lastfile=filename;
}' file.log
```

The `close` keeps the open file table from filling up.

Comment: Thanks for the awk solution.  I already come with something similar.  My question was to understand the bash limitation, not to find an alternate solution.