# Add consecutive numbers succintly and elegantly to index lines

Tags: vim, numbering, seq

I usually do this

```
$ wc questions
  33   36 3105 questions
$ seq 1 33 > nums
$ paste nums questions
1       Content
2       ...
.
.
33      End Content
```

but I feel there could be faster way to do this, without the bad-looking dummy file. How with some basic *ix -tool? Any simpler way to do it? I use Vim so I am happy also with Vim-based solution but simple unix-based solution also works (actually probably better in some cases, I can always spawn inside the editor).

Below a general case.

**Input**

```
A
B
C
.
.
X
```

**Output**

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
.
.
N. X
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the completeness of this list, `sed` can also do it:

```
sed '=' questions | sed 'N;s/\n/. /'
```

Sadly the `=` command *prints* the line numbers on separate line, so only a separated `sed` call can beautify the formatting.

Answer (score 17):

This is exactly what `nl` is for. For example, assuming `file.txt` contains your sample input, and you want it to look like your sample output, you could do:

```
nl -nln '-s. ' file.txt
```

The manpage for `nl` goes into greater detail on its use. It gives you a lot of control over the output format.

Comment: Wow.  I've been using *IX since the mid 1980's and I'd never used or heard of `nl`.

Comment: I had to look it up, but according to FreeBSD, it dates to SVR2.

Comment: surely not POSIX. It's not on OpenBSD. Though I knew it existed before but I will strongly advise not to use it in scripts. A little "idx=0;for i in `cat file`; do echo $idx $i; idx=`eval $idx + 1` ; done" should do the trick (didn't test, but surely you see the point). You could use an editor like vim/view to look at the file and configure it to print line numbers too, you'll have syntax colors as well hey.

Comment: I remember `nl` from late-80s Unix tutorials, listed along with command such as `cat` and `ls`. It made a lot of sense in the days of dot matrix printouts and sprocket paper, but it has its place and I still find call for it.

Comment: @Aki: The [FreeBSD manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nl&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+4.7-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) from 4.7-RELEASE onward claims it conforms to POSIX.1, and it's listed in the [Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/nl.html) version 2.

Comment: @Aki you can use `cat -n` in many cases.  I'm not sure if the `-n` option is an extension or POSIX.  I know that it is not listed in SUS but [Rob Pike was complaining about it in 1983](http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/).

Comment: To number **all** line, it also needs `-ba`. otherwise it numbers only non-blank lines and yet still prints the un-numbered blank lines, meaning that the line numbers don't increment to reflect the actual number of newlines... This fixes it: `nl -nln -ba -s'. '`

Comment: Nice catch, Peter!

Answer (score 13):

I'm surprised `cat -n` hasn't been mentioned by now.

Comment: Too standard. It can make things portable...

Comment: I just mentioned that `cat -n` in another comment. I was surprised that the `-n` option isn't part of the Single Unix Specification.

Answer (score 4):

In Vim you could add line numbers to the actual text of a buffer like this:

```
:%s/^/\=printf('%5d. ',line('.'))
```

The `\=` (see [`:help sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)) lets the replacement string be treated as a VimL expression. The expression used here is a simple formatting of the current line number.

You could make it a bit fancier by automatically calculating and using a minimal width (instead of the “hard coded” 5, as above) for the current number of lines in the file:

```
:%s/^/\=printf('%*d. ',len(line('$')),line('.'))
```

Or, left-justified:

```
:%s/^/\=printf('%d.%*s ',line('.'),len(line('$'))-len(line('.')),'')
```

Of course, if you just want to see the line numbers and do not care to have them actually in the buffer’s data, then you should just use

```
:set number
```

---

From the shell, you might find `cat -n` or `pr -tn` useful.

Comment: Sweet. He could even map the commands to a key. But for the first example I'd rather write a shell script and execute it than open the file on vim and enter this command each time (or press a key) and quit vim then print my file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your constraints are regarding the separation between the number and the data, but i'd do: `grep -n '^' questions`. That would output:

```
1:Content
2:...


33:End Content
```

Comment: Using just `.` as the regex, it will not output blank lines... Using `'.*'` will .

Comment: So will `^` as the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Some other solutions:

Exactly what you were doing, without the temporary file:

```
seq 1 $(wc -l questions | cut -f 1 -d " ") | paste - questions
```

But `cat -n` is much better as above fails if the `questions` file change between the call to `wc` and `paste`.

If you want to avoid creating a process you could:

```
{ N=1; while read line; do printf "%d %s\n" $N "$line"; N=$(($N + 1)); done; } < questions
```

But do not try the above if you have a large file, especially because the following `bash` [bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33170/bash-scripting-and-large-files-bug-input-with-the-read-builtin-from-a-redirec).

Comment: You can spare the `cut`. When `wc` processes STDIN outputs no file name: `seq 1 $(wc -l < questions) | paste - questions`

Comment: In this case, cut does not process STDIN output, it process the `questions` file.